# Strange Handle must be valid Exception in Dialog

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin.android

I'm getting reports that I'm getting misbehaving in my application. I show a sync successful dialog to let the user know their data has been synced. Some users had said they do not get the sync successful dialog and the progress bar just stays at 100%/100% and they need to press back to exit.

The issue isn't easy to reproduce, in fact, I'm not able to really do it but logs we create that take the exceptions show the area that is an issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Classes;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
using Services;
using System.Threading;
using Helpers;

namespace Dialogs
{
    public class ProgressBarDialog : DialogFragment
    {
        private ProgressBar progressBar;
        private OnProgressFinished onProgressFinished;
        int _countSeconds;
        object _lock = new object();
        private TextView progressText;
        private LinearLayout titleBackground;
        private Button yes, no;
        private static string title, description;
        private OnItemClick callback;

        public interface OnItemClick
        {
            void OnItemClick(int id);
        }

        public interface OnProgressFinished
        {
            void OnProgressFinished(int id);
        }

        public static ProgressBarDialog NewInstance(Bundle bundle, string passedTitle, string passedDesc)
        {
            var fragment = new ProgressBarDialog();
            title = passedTitle;
            description = passedDesc;
            return fragment;
        }

        public override void OnAttach(Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            base.OnAttach(context);
            try
            {
                callback = (OnItemClick)context;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
            }

            try
            {
                onProgressFinished = (OnProgressFinished)context;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e);
            }
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //return customview for the fragment
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ProgressDialog, container, false);
            progressBar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
            progressText = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.progressText);
            progressBar.Max = 100;
            SampleDatabase db = new SampleDatabase();
            SampleRESTFulService save = new SampleRESTFulService(Activity);
            List<Sample> samples = db.Get();
            int sampleCount = samples.Count;

            if (sampleCount > 0)
            {
                Activity.RunOnUiThread(async () =>
                {
                    using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
                    {
                        cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

                        try
                        {
                            int successfullySynced = 0;
                            foreach (Sample sample in samples.ToArray())
                            {
                                cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                if (sample.Tag.Equals("NR"))
                                {
                                    db.Delete(sample);
                                }

                                bool isSuccess = await save.SaveAsync(sample, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                                if (isSuccess)
                                {
                                    ++successfullySynced;
                                    db.Delete(sample);
                                    samples.Remove(sample);
                                    progressBar.Progress = successfullySynced * 100 / sampleCount;
                                    progressText.Text = progressBar.Progress.ToString() + "%";
                                }
                                else if (isSuccess == false && cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                                {
                                    onProgressFinished.OnProgressFinished(1);
                                    Dismiss();
                                }

                                CheckProgress(progressBar.Progress);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            LoggerHelper.LogUser("ProgressBarDialog OnCreateView Error", ex.ToString());

                            Console.WriteLine(ex);
                        }

                        if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            Dismiss();
                            onProgressFinished.OnProgressFinished(1);
                        }
                        else if (progressBar != null && progressBar.Progress < 100)
                        {
                            Dismiss();
                            onProgressFinished.OnProgressFinished(1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return view;
        }

        // This is the function where the exception is kicking off.
        public void CheckProgress(int progress)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (progress >= 100)
                    {
                        Dismiss();
                        onProgressFinished.OnProgressFinished(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggerHelper.LogUser("ProgressBarDialog CheckProgress Error", ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The exception I'm getting is :

> 4/10/2020 1:15:58 PM] - System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid.
>   Parameter name: instance
>     at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00009] in <8cb56b2f65354c9f9fbb25da78a6cf09>:0
>     at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in :0
>     at Android.Content.ISharedPreferencesEditorInvoker.PutString (System.String key, System.String value) [0x0006c] in :0
>     at Activities.SampleListActivity.OnProgressFinished (System.Int32 id) [0x00154] in :0
>     at Dialogs.ProgressBarDialog.CheckProgress (System.Int32 progress) [0x00022] in :0

My callback function is like so:

```
public void OnProgressFinished(int id)
        {
            if (id == 1)
            {
                if (!IsFinishing && informDialog != null && IsForeground)
                {
                    editor.PutString("Name", "");
                    editor.Commit();
                    updateAdapter();
                    informDialog.Dismiss();

                    SampleDatabase sDb = new SampleDatabase();
                    if(sDb.Get().ToArray().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        TrySyncAgain();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!IsFinishing && informDialog != null && IsForeground)
                        {
                            editor.PutString("PASSEDHERD", "");
                            editor.Commit();
                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            alert.SetTitle("Sync Successful");
                            alert.SetMessage("You're samples have been synced successfully.");
                            alert.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (senderAlert, args) =>
                            {
                                LoggerHelper.LogUser(passedHerd.Tech_ID, string.Format("{0} clicked OK on sync successful.", passedHerd.Tech_ID));
                                LoggerHelper.Log(passedHerd.Herd_Test_ID, String.Format("User: {0}, pressed Yes on sync successful", passedHerd.Tech_ID));
                                End(true);
                            });
                            Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                            dialog.Show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            else if (id == 0)
            {
                if (!IsFinishing && informDialog != null && IsForeground)
                {
                    editor.PutString("PASSEDHERD", "");
                    editor.Commit();
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alert.SetTitle("Sync Successful");
                    alert.SetMessage("You're samples have been synced successfully.");
                    alert.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (senderAlert, args) =>
                    {
                        LoggerHelper.LogUser(passedHerd.Tech_ID, string.Format("{0} clicked OK on sync successful.", passedHerd.Tech_ID));
                        LoggerHelper.Log(passedHerd.Herd_Test_ID, String.Format("User: {0}, pressed Yes on sync successful", passedHerd.Tech_ID));
                        End(true);
                    });
                    Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                    dialog.Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried passing Null into the callback but it won't take it due to the Int value needed.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just an update on findings. I researched that the SDK version and OS might have effects on the shared preferences. I made the min and max SDK to 25(7.1) which was 23 before. And made the OS for the build 7.1 which was 8.0 before. The app won't be on the Play Store. I also feel that when the Shared Preferences is global it might lose the "this" context so I'm thinking of also changing to "Application". Still haven't been able to recreate to date :/

Comment: Anything that outlives the activity must be obtained from the application Context

Comment: also, a more conventional way to edit a shared preferences:
`someSharedPref.Edit().PutString("key", "Value").Commit()`

Comment: or better : 
`someSharedPref.Edit().PutString("key", "Value").Apply()`

Comment: Hey @bwt thanks for that, certainly going to try adding this to better my application. The exception was just really weird as it mentioned instance was the value passed, have you had this before?

Comment: As I understand it, the .NET runtime has a JNI reference on a native object that doesn't exist anymore. I don't know how this can happen.

Comment: but the Application object is a singleton, it should never disappear

Comment: Could you tell us what versions, of Xamarin.Essentials, and Xamarin.Android you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firebase Testlab and install Crashlytics. This will help you see in realtime when the user app crash. This has helped me a lot

Comment: thanks for your information. We do have a crash analytics within the application. The problem with this is that it doesn't actually crash since we catch the exception, and in that we weren't getting a proper stack trace when it's in production. We needed to add logs which we were able to find the cause. But the issue here is that the exception isn't really helpful either, and we can't recreate the crash. So hoping to get some guidance. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: Did you try the Test Lab with multiple devices and versions? create a pattern and then run it. This will show the behavior. This might be in and specific device or android version.

Comment: We haven't, unfortunately it's it used on one device and one version. It's a client application so they need to pay. I've made a change which bwt mentioned and been testing that, but since we couldn't recreate it before, has it actually fixed it :/

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be with the Tarjan Garbage Collector that was introduced in Xaramarin.Android version 7 ("Cycle8"). However, people report the problem is possible with the old Garbage Collector its less likely. Looking at your code:

```
else if (id == 0)
{
    if (!IsFinishing && informDialog != null && IsForeground)
    {
        editor.PutString("PASSEDHERD", ""); //-- This is the line causing you issues.
        editor.Commit();
        ...
     }
}
```

It seems to me that at some point the systems that are having this error have the garbage collector run at just the wrong point (possibly when the system is low on memory, but I have no way to test this).

There seem to be a few fixes and workarounds out there. The first being to add the flag "*MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=old*" to the build, however, this will just reduce the frequency of the issue not remove it altogether.
Next is to use Xamarin.Android 7 ("Cycle 7") or below where the issue does not occur, however, this is a large downgrade if you are using an update to date version.

Finally, there is a fix patched into version 0.9.0 of Xamarin.Essentials, where they claimed to fixed the SharedPrefereces issue.

Here is my research for this:
https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/51/51478/bug.html
https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/47/47577/bug.html

https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/380 
https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/pull/386